# Heroku push of django app gets "No module named psycopg2.extensions"

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to push a django app to heroku and getting an error that I haven't seen anywhere in the heroku or stackoverflow forums.  I'm using postgres.

I'm not sure where to proceed; I see nothing in any of the docs that says what is wrong.  The main error is:

**ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions**

...but heroku's configuration is the one that is setting that as the ENGINE, I don't know how to get by it.

My conversation with heroku to make sure it knows about postgres

```
$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev
Adding heroku-postgresql:dev on morning-crag-1585... done, v24 (free)
Attached as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL
Database has been created and is available
 ! This database is empty. If upgrading, you can transfer
 ! data from another database with pgbackups:restore.
.
Use `heroku addons:docs heroku-postgresql:dev` to view documentation.
$ heroku pg:wait 
$ heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL: postgres://<blah-blah-blah>@ec2-<ip-address>.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/<blah-blah>
$ heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL
Promoting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL to DATABASE_URL... done
```

My requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.4.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
dj-database-url==0.2.1
```

A snippet from my settings.py:

```
print "Got here before!\n"
try:
  import dj_database_url
  DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost') }
except:
  print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()

print DATABASES
```

When I push to heroku, I get this from `heroku logs`:

```
heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:30550 --noreload`
app[web.1]: Got here before!
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'NAME': '<blah blah>', 'HOST': 'ec2-<iip-address>.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'USER': '<blah blah>', 'PASSWORD': '<blah>', 'PORT': 5432}}
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: Validating models...
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:   File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
app[web.1]:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
app[web.1]:     utility.execute()
app[web.1]:     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
app[web.1]:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
app[web.1]:     self.inner_run(*args, **options)
app[web.1]:     self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
app[web.1]:     num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
app[web.1]:     self.run(*args, **options)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
app[web.1]:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
app[web.1]:     from django.db import models, connection
app[web.1]:     return import_module('.base', backend_name)
app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions
app[web.1]:     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/creation.py", line 1, in <module>
app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
app[web.1]:     import psycopg2.extensions
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 69, in handle
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in run
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
app[web.1]:     from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.creation import DatabaseCreation
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 13, in <module>
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add the `psycopg2` installation to your `requirements.txt` file. It is the database adapter - the way python interfaces with the PostgreSQL you indeed do not need to install because heroku does.

Just add the line `psycopg2==2.4.4` to your `requirements.txt` file.

The database add-on addition itself, by the way, is not necessary. `dj-database-url` takes care of it automatically. Check out the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) for a step-by-step guide.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks!  That did it, and closer read of the docs (I'd been reading them over and over but somehow missed that one line)

Comment: Should apply the latest version to make it work： https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/ 

I added `psycopg2==2.9.3` which finally work it out

Answer (score 2):

I installed psycopg2-binary.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

added to **requirements.txt** file.

Committed and pushed the code and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the accepted answer but it kept giving me same error again and again. So I had to change my requirements.txt file. 
FROM: `psycopg2==2.7.7`  TO: `psycopg2-binary` .

Now it is working perfectly fine.For more details go to the doc: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am using Flask. Typing psycopg or psycopg binary into requirements.txt didn't help. My solution was:

- exit python and access the virtual environment
- `pip install psycopg2-binary`

And everything worked perfectly.