# "Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'" after changing database on django

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I'm a bit of a beginner with Django so forgive me if I'm missing some necessary information. I recently revised my database on settings.py and I keep getting an error when I run

```
    git push heroku master
```

The error block looks like:

```
    Counting objects: 22, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 4.84 KiB | 825.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.8
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
remote:            import psycopg2 as Database
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv   )
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line  
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
remote:            app_config.import_models()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
remote:            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
remote:            class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 101, in __new__
remote:            new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
remote:            value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
remote:            self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
remote:            return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
remote:            backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
remote:            return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:             return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:           File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/  base.py", line 24, in <module>
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module    named 'psycopg2'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ewbunlv.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ewbunlv.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ewbunlv.git'
```

This is the part of my settings.py that I changed (originally the default database Django has)

```
    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', #Used 'django.db.backends.postgresql' as well
            'NAME': 'myname',
            USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': 'host',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

my requirements.txt:

```
    awscli==1.16.91
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.9.81
botocore==1.12.81
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.4
django-cleanup==3.0.1
django-s3-folder-storage==0.5
django-storages==1.7.1
docutils==0.14
gunicorn==19.9.0
heroku==0.1.4
idna==2.8
jmespath==0.9.3
Pillow==5.3.0
pyasn1==0.4.5
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.7
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.21.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.1
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

I've run

```
    heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput
```

and it works perfectly fine, no errors whatsoever. I've been working on this for a while now to no avail.

It works fine locally as well, but when I try to translate it to production, I get the error mentioned above. What am I missing?

Comment: Is that section from your `settings.py` accurate? There's an obvious quote error that should prevent your app from working at all(look at the syntax highlighting).

Comment: Also, it looks like `psycopg2` isn't included in your dependencies. Why isn't it? You're clearly trying to use it.

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL locally, or just on Heroku? It's usually a _**very**_ good idea to use the same database provider in all of your environments, including your development environment. Library mismatches are one of the many reasons why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku push of django app gets "No module named psycopg2.extensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620051/heroku-push-of-django-app-gets-no-module-named-psycopg2-extensions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+%22No+module+named+psycopg2%22

Comment: You should add `psycopg2-binary==2.7.7` to your `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 6):

1. disable the collectstatic during a deploy

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

2. deploy

```
git push heroku master (or git push heroku <branch>:master if not on master)
```

3. run migrations

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

4. run collectstatic using bower

```
heroku run 'bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'
```

5. enable collecstatic for future deploys

```
heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC
```

6. Run collectstatic again

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris, phd, and Selcuk mentioned, it seems I overlooked some necessary parts in my requirements.txt file. I used

```
    pip freeze
```

and copy/pasted onto the requirements.txt file again and this time it worked.

Comment: You know you can do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to print the output of pip freeze directly into requrements.txt?